# Retrieve job Details in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How do I retrieve information about a SQL Server Agent job scheduled against databases on SQL server 2005?

Answer (score 6):

Jobs are DB agnostic: the steps that comprise a job may have a database context

[sysjobsteps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187387.aspx) has a database_name column

> Name of the database in which command is executed if subsystem is TSQL.

You can join this back to [sysjobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189817.aspx) and the other related tables to get what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but if the subsystem is SSIS  then the  Database Name in the sysjobsteps is null.

Comment: @John: of course. These details are in the SSIS package...

Comment: can u please help how I can retrive the same details if the Subsystem is SSIS

Comment: @John: sorry, you can't from SQL Server.

Comment: What is the other Way???

Comment: @John: no idea. You'd have to open the package somehow (perhaps using CLR) and read the details there. However, if there are variables or config files then the info won't be in the package until run time.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment string with gbn, I'd recommend that you connect to the SSIS instance using SSMS. Then you would find the specific package (under "Stored Packages" and either "File System" or "MSDB") and right-click the package and export it. You'd wand to choose "File System" for the destination. The you can edit the package inVS.